# Carrera impel IS1 scooter

Tags: electric-bike, battery, motor

customer brought in carrera impel IS1 scooter and its pretty new. Max speed should be 15.5mph at the moment it goes just under 10mph. New motor, new ECU been fitted. Is it something to do with the battery?
Thank you.

[image]

https://www.halfords.com/scooters/electric-scooters/carrera-impel-is-1-electric-scooter-451870.html

Comment: Does the scooter have any kind of speed sensor that isn't properly connected or cables damaged?

Comment: If "pretty new" means its under warranty, tell the owner to take it back to Halfords or whereever they purchased it from.   No point throwing parts at it or voiding the warranty and costing the owner more money than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If this were a regular ebike I might guess that your new controller may need some configuration which would be described in the manual. This is assuming you got a replacement from the manufacturer.